# JavaScript getting JSON string from Python server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm not a JavaScript programmer, and I'm trying to dabble in jquery.

I know that if I have string in the form:

`var myList=[{"Tank1": 45000, "Tank2": -10}, {"Tank1": 200, "Tank2": 435}]`

the javascript code which I've copied can read it, and use it.

My question, is how do I get the same list as a variable "myList", when it comes from JSON. My python server code outputs JSON as:

```
[{"Tank1": 45000, "Tank2": -10}, {"Tank1": 200, "Tank2": 435}]
```

Could someone show me how I can read this into javascript as a variable "myList", please?  Do I also need any specific .js libraries?

Comment: response from python server is stored in a variable too if u use $.ajax function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function to make it json object using jQuery.

```
$.parseJSON('[{"Tank1": 45000, "Tank2": -10}, {"Tank1": 200, "Tank2": 435}]');
```

OR

```
$.parseJSON(varibleContainingJsonString);
```